# How to make work multiple telegram bots at one Laravel instance

Tags: php, laravel, bots, telegram, messenger

I need opportunity to work with multiple telegram bots in one Laravel instance. The method suggested in Irazasyed telegram driver doesn`t suit me. Because it involves use telegram bot API key in webhook link(that not secure I think), and cant interact with other bot accounts in code flow. 
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **shapoapps/multibot_driver** package 
(composer require shapoapps/multibot_driver)
Allows you to work with multiple number of telegram bots simultaneously on a single instance of Laravel. 
Group bots and specify for groups
personal settings. For more information, see the documentation https://github.com/shapoapps/multibot_driver . 
More powerful than features
built-in telegram drivers.

Comment: this repo deleted is there any clone repo there? i cant search via google. did you clone it?